Why is hamburger icon disabled when adding an options menu?
I have a DrawerLayout set up and everything is working fine. Until I create an options menu in one of my fragments via requireActivity().addMenuProvider(...). With that a tap on the hamburger icon doesn't open the drawer anymore. I can still slide it in from the left though. On other fragments that don't provide a menu the hamburger icon is working fine.
Is there a way to have a menu in some fragments and still have the hamburger icon open the drawer?
EDIT: This is from my MainActivity's onCreate method:
    val navController = findNavController(R.id.nav_host_fragment)
    val topDest = setOf(R.id.scanner_fragment, R.id.products_fragment, R.id.categories_fragment)
    appBarConfiguration = AppBarConfiguration(topDest, binding.drawerLayout)
    setupActionBarWithNavController(navController, appBarConfiguration)
    binding.navView.setupWithNavController(navController)

and this is from the fragment that provides a menu:
private val menuProvider = object : MenuProvider {
    override fun onCreateMenu(menu: Menu, menuInflater: MenuInflater) {
        menuInflater.inflate(R.menu.menu, menu)
    }

    override fun onMenuItemSelected(menuItem: MenuItem): Boolean {
        when (menuItem.itemId) {
            R.id.flashlight -> {
                val iconId = toggleFlashLight()
                menuItem.icon = ContextCompat.getDrawable(requireContext(), iconId)
            }
        }
        return true
    }
}

override fun onStart() {
    super.onStart()
    requireActivity().addMenuProvider(menuProvider)
}

override fun onPause() {
    super.onPause()
    requireActivity().removeMenuProvider(menuProvider)
}


How do you hook your hamburger icon up to your drawer? What does your MenuProvider return from onMenuItemSelected? Please include enough code to reproduce your problem.

@ianhanniballake: I've added some code

So why is your MenuProvider always returning true, instead of only returning true on the item you are actually handling?

For the why unfortunately I don't have an answer. But I refactored my code to return true only on the item and false else; that did the trick. Thank you for the hint.

ianhanniballake's comment brought me on the right track. This is what the onMenuItemSelected method should look like:
    override fun onMenuItemSelected(menuItem: MenuItem): Boolean {
        return when (menuItem.itemId) {
            R.id.flashlight -> {
                val iconId = toggleFlashLight()
                menuItem.icon = ContextCompat.getDrawable(requireContext(), iconId)
                true
            }
            else -> false
        }
    }

